# Cannot set file descriptor to nonblocking

Tags: c++, nonblocking, epoll

How does the following execution possible:

```
int set_result = fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, O_NONBLOCK); // set_result: 0
int get_result = fcntl(fd, F_GETFD);             // get_result: 0
```

For some reason fcntl cannot set fd to non-blocking and does not signal about it. And, as expected, the next read from this fd blocks.

Answer (score 1):

That's because [the right magic incantation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) is `F_SETFL` and `F_GETFL`.